# Element ref was specified as a string (inner) but no owner was set

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a navbar through react bootstrap but somehow it is not working out for me. The problem is the Navbar, if I remove the whole Navbar tags it works fine.  Not able to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {Nav, Navbar, NavItem, MenuItem, NavDropdown,Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import './style.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';

export default class Header extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return(
      <Navbar>
      <Nav bsStyle="pills" stacked activeKey={1}>
  <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/home">
   NavItem 1 content
  </NavItem>
  <NavItem eventKey={2} title="Item">
   NavItem 2 content
  </NavItem>
  <NavItem eventKey={3} disabled>
   NavItem 3 content
  </NavItem>
 </Nav>
  </Navbar>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be due to a deprecation in React 16 - I had the same problem when using react (and react-dom) 16.2.0, but I got it to work by downgrading to 15.6.1.

Comment: I uninstalled all dependencies and reinstalled all dependencies and it worked for me. I was not able to figure out the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Probably you installed "react react-dom" packages before installing react-bootstrap, as said in [react-bootstrap's getting started page](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/), while you had already it installed.

uninstalling it has solved me.

```
npm uninstall  react react-dom
```

see [Multiple copies of React](https://reactjs.org/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html#multiple-copies-of-react)